# Why my function is not returning a value using another function as input?

Tags: mysql, function

I have written two functions. The first one utilized a select query and returns a value. While my second function uses the returned value from the first function as input and after certain operation should return its own value. Though I am getting'OK' Message but not getting any output

```
DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS walkerCubicAreaWeight;
CREATE FUNCTION walkerCubicAreaWeight (WType1 CHAR(5))
RETURNS DECIMAL(5,2)

BEGIN 
DECLARE Cubic_Area_Weight  FLOAT;
SELECT Weight INTO @A FROM imperial_walker_type WHERE WType = WType1;
SELECT Height INTO @B FROM imperial_walker_type WHERE WType = WType1;
SELECT Length INTO @C FROM imperial_walker_type WHERE WType = WType1;
SELECT Width INTO @D FROM imperial_walker_type WHERE WType = WType1;

SET Cubic_Area_Weight = @A/(@B*@C*@D) ;
RETURN Cubic_Area_Weight;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

## Function 2

```
DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS walkerFuelCapacity;
CREATE FUNCTION walkerFuelCapacity (WType1 varCHAR(20))
RETURNS DECIMAL(10,2)

BEGIN 
DECLARE Walker_Fuel_Capacity FLOAT;
SELECT OpRange INTO @E FROM imperial_walker_type WHERE WType = WType1;
SET Walker_Fuel_Capacity = walkerCubicAreaWeight(WType1) *@E ;
RETURN Walker_Fuel_Capacity;
END  //

DELIMITER ;
```

My First function is returning value 0.40. In the second function it should utilize 0.40 and multiple it with oprange(in this case it is 720) and should return 288. However I am getting message OK and no value

Comment: Can you add how you execute this (e.g. what gives you the "OK"-message)?

Comment: I call walkerFuelCapacity function  in a SELECT query. Like the one below. -                             select count(*),walkerFuelCapacity('AT-AT') from imperial_walker_type

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get an answer to my question above.

The above two functions were part of the stored procedure using a cursor. I was trying to run these function in a separate query i.e.(out of stored procedure) and hence the second function was not returning any results however within stored procedure I got my desired results. Thank You.